# Unzip JSON file from URL swiftui

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, decode, zlib

I am trying to unzip a file from an URL via the zlib protocol. I wrote a function (loadData) that should first get the compressed Data, then decompress it, then decode it (JSON decoder) and finally put it into the variable "spotdata".
However, nothing shows up on my simulator or preview. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

```
struct ContentView: View {   

    @State var spotData = WindAppSpot()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("\(spotData.spot)")
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    
    func loadData() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/Bene2907/Bene2907.github.io/raw/main/outfile.dat") else {
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decompressedData = try (data as NSData).decompressed(using: .zlib)
                    if let response_obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WindAppSpot.self, from: decompressedData as Data) {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.spotData = response_obj
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The structure looks something like this:

```
struct WindAppSpot: Decodable {
    var spot: String
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Remove the question mark at the end of `try?` and replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error` to catch at least a potential error.

Comment: I tried that but then the Error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'WindAppSpot'" occured, I think this is because our structure is later used as an observable object and therefore the variables are written like "var spot: String? = "no spot". Is there any other way of unzipping while still using this structure?

Comment: Of course you have to remove also `if` and the both braces.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did that and the code doesn't throw any errors anymore, however, when running, it still doesn't work and the console prints "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=5377 "(null)""